# CDF of a density function with absolute value.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If X is a random variable with the density function $f(x)=\frac{e^{-|x|}}{2}$, what is the CDF of X?

My first inclination is to take $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{x}/2\,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\int_{-\infty}^0 \mathrm{e}^{-x}/2\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Is this all?

Comment: @Stefanos, just changed it.

Comment: Ok, I saw it. The integral limits should be from $-\infty$ to $x$. The integral you have is equal to 1, is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $$f(x)=\frac{e^{-|x|}}{2}$$ which is the Laplace distribution, your idea of splitting the function is correct! But, the cdf is itself a function not a single number! That means that your integration limits should depend on x. Therefore, you have to disriminate cases according to the value of x:

1. $x\le 0$: then $$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)~dt=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{e^t}{2}~dt$$
2. $x>0$: then $$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)~dt=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{e^t}{2}~dt+\int_{0}^{x}\frac{e^{-t}}{2}~dt$$

Comment: The first term in the second is a constant that can be evaluated, but it is good to show it in this form.  That can be left as an exercise.

Comment: @Stefanos Ok, I understand that the CDF is the antiderivative of the density function. But for x less than or equal to zero, why is it $$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)~dt=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{e^t}{2}~dt$$ instead of $$F_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)~dt=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{e^{-t}}{2}~dt$$

I'm looking at a graph of f(x), and from negative infinity to zero, the function seems to be $e^{(-x)}$. I having trouble wrapping my head around this.

Comment: @MMP For $x<0$ you have that $-|x|=-(-x)=x$. The exponent in th term $e^t$ is indeed negative, when we are in the interval $(-\infty, 0)$. If we write $e^{-t}$ as you say, then try to plug in some negative numbers for $t$ to see what happens...

Comment: @Stefanos Sorry for bothering you again. I tried to apply the logic you provided for $x\le 0$ for $x$ greater than 0, but the second part where the exponent is negative for limits 0 to $x$ is tripping me up again.

Comment: @Stefanos I figured it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MMP Take it this way. The exponent should always be negative, otherwise $e^x$ will explode and will be a legitimate density function that integrates to $1$. So when $x$ is **itself** negative, we write $e^x$ and when $x$ is **itself** positive we write $e^{-x}$! Revise a little the absolut values and you will have it...