# CDF with absolute value

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am working on a problem that is finding the CDF of a random variable X from a density function that has an absolute value. My question shares some similarity to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728170/cdf-of-a-density-function-with-absolute-value) where I imagine to solve it, you need to use some sort of splitting of the integration.

The problem: Find the CDF for the random variable from:

f(x) = $|x|\over10$, on -2$\le$x$\le$4

0, otherwise

**What I have done so far:**

Fx(x) = $\int_{-\infty}^{-2}$f(x) d(x) = 0

Fx(x) = $\int_{-2}^4$ f(x) d(x) = 1

**The CDF is something along the lines of:**

Fx(x) = $1\over10$$\int_{a}^0$|x|d(x) + $1\over10$$\int_{0}^{a}$|x|d(x)

Not sure if I am on the right track here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^y f(x) \ dx$

if $y< 0$

$F(y) = \int_{-2}^y \frac {-x}{10} \ dx$

if $y\ge 0$

$F(y) = \int_{-2}^0 \frac {-x}{10} \ dx + \int_0^y \frac {x}{10} \ dx$

Giving you a piece-wise function.

Comment: Just for clarification, why on the last one do we include the integral from -2 to 0 if they y is greater than or equal to zero?

Comment: It is a cumulative distribution.  $\int_{-\infty}^y f(x)\ dx = \int_{-\infty}^{-2} f(x)\ dx + \int_{-2}^{0} f(x)\ dx + \int_{0}^{y} f(x)\ dx$  Just because we are looking at some $y > 0$ doesn't mean that everything to the right of that $y$ isn't accumulated.  It will create a constant, that is not trivial in the final result.